# Colorbox over colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Let's say I have following link:

```
<p><a class='iframe' href="iframe.html">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
```

And script :

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"800px", height:"600px"});
```

In that `iframe.html` iI have another colorbox link:

```
<a class="group1" href="../content/ohoopee1.jpg">Grouped Photo 1</a>
```

:

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1', width:"800px", height:"600px"});
```

Now the second colorbox content shows up in the first colorbox content. Colorboxes are "nested":

[image]

Is it possible that the colorbox called from that iframe will pop up over the first colorbox. I want to cover first colorbox, and show it again when the second colorbox is closed.

Hope you understand what I want to achieve, because I am not an English native, and it seems a little complicated to explain my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pop it over the first because there can only be one instance of colorbox open in a document, you can only replace the first.  For the first to re-open when closing the 2nd, you'd have to write a short script to replace colorbox's close method so that it takes a different action instead.